# button Stop/Cancel progressBar from subprocess PYGTK

Tags: python, progress-bar, pygtk

I have been trying to add a cancel button to a progressbar en pygtk but now way to get the funcion. What its does that function is execute and script and every line in the output count it and is added to the progressBar. My problem is how to cancel that subprocess, is there a way?

```
def stop(self, widget):
    print "cancelar"
    os.killpg(self.p.pid, signal.SIGTERM) #=> not working
    self.p.kill() #=> not working


count = 0
command = "script.sh"
self.p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, bufsize=0, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)


for line in iter(self.p.stdout.readline, ""):
    count = count + 1

    while gtk.events_pending():
        gtk.mainiteration()
        gobject.timeout_add(1000, self.update)
        porcentaje = float(count) / float(1400)
        print porcentaje
        self.progress.set_text(str(int(porcentaje * 100)) + "%")
        self.progress.set_fraction(porcentaje)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example should do everything you are asking for (hopefully), it prints the output of a long running command in two textviews, in the top one the stdout and in the bottom one the stderr.

You can kill the process with the stop button and the progress will stop pulsing.

In the meantime the UI should not freeze without using threads, it should work on windows too (not too sure but I'm quite confident it will) but you will have to change 'du' in something else of course.

It uses GTK3, so pygobject with introspection (and you should use it too...) but if you really want to use PyGTK it should be pretty straightforward to port.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib
import os, signal

class MySpawned(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_default_size(600,600)

        vb = Gtk.VBox(False, 5)

        self.tw_out = Gtk.TextView()

        sw = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        vb.pack_start(sw, True, True, 0)
        sw.add(self.tw_out)

        self.tw_err = Gtk.TextView()

        sw = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        vb.pack_start(sw, True, True, 0)
        sw.add(self.tw_err)

        self.progress = Gtk.ProgressBar()
        vb.pack_start(self.progress, False, True, 0)

        bt = Gtk.Button('Run')
        bt.connect('clicked', self.process)
        vb.pack_start(bt, False, False, 0)

        bt = Gtk.Button('Stop')
        bt.connect('clicked', self.kill)
        vb.pack_start(bt, False, False, 0)

        self.add(vb)
        self.set_size_request(200, 300)
        self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()

    def update_progress(self, data=None):
        self.progress.pulse()
        return True

    def kill(self, widget, data=None):
        os.kill(self.pid, signal.SIGTERM)

    def process(self, widget, data=None):
        params = ['du', '--si', '/']

        def scroll_to_end(textview):
            i = textview.props.buffer.get_end_iter()
            mark = textview.props.buffer.get_insert()
            textview.props.buffer.place_cursor(i)
            textview.scroll_to_mark(mark, 0.0, True, 0.0, 1.0)

        def write_to_textview(io, condition, tw):
            if condition is GLib.IO_HUP:
                GLib.source_remove(self.source_id_out)
                GLib.source_remove(self.source_id_err)
                return False

            line = io.readline()
            tw.props.buffer.insert_at_cursor(line)
            scroll_to_end(tw)

            while Gtk.events_pending():
                Gtk.main_iteration_do(False)

            return True

        self.pid, stdin, stdout, stderr = GLib.spawn_async(params,
            flags=GLib.SpawnFlags.SEARCH_PATH|GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD,                                       
            standard_output=True,
            standard_error=True)

        self.progress.set_text('Running du --si')

        io = GLib.IOChannel(stdout)
        err = GLib.IOChannel(stderr)

        self.source_id_out = io.add_watch(GLib.IO_IN|GLib.IO_HUP,
                                 write_to_textview,
                                 self.tw_out,
                                 priority=GLib.PRIORITY_HIGH)

        self.source_id_err = err.add_watch(GLib.IO_IN|GLib.IO_HUP,
                                 write_to_textview,
                                 self.tw_err,
                                 priority=GLib.PRIORITY_HIGH)

        timeout_id = GLib.timeout_add(100, self.update_progress)

        def closure_func(pid, status, data):
            GLib.spawn_close_pid(pid)
            GLib.source_remove(timeout_id)
            self.progress.set_fraction(0.0)

        GLib.child_watch_add(self.pid, closure_func, None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = MySpawned()
    s.run()
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but i don`t want a pulsebar. What im trying to do, is cancel the loop, and the functions "os.killpg(self.p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)" and "self.p.kill()" is not working. do you have any clue how to stop/cancel the subprocess en the loop? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @ruben, I don't think it's not working, I think you are blocking the UI (mainloop) when you run the subprocess and the control in not released until the subprocess is finished, but it's just my guess by looking at the portion of code you have posted. That's why in the example I have used the async function to spawn the process. If I'm mistaking please post a code that works showing the problem. Cheers

Comment: @ruben, that's what is happening, unless you run the subprocess in a separate thread you won't be able to kill the process itself, messing with threads can be really painful though, I suggest you to change the code as I pointed out in the example, run the process through the spawn_async function and read the pipe (stdout) with a IOChannel. That way you will be able to kill the process as in my example.

Comment: buff dont tell me that, i dont know how to adapt you code since is not mine and im really a noob i will be lost. can you make a simple adaptation for me please? if you want of course. Otherwise i can pass away running an script in the cancel button and i kill it directly, but if i can do it on python much better! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @ruben sure I'm willing to help but you will have to cut down the code  and make a sample of a reasonable amount of lines, that's just too much code (including a lot of stuff on your local machine) to edit.